# Accessing Gridview columns by Row.Cells

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

Hai I am using the following code to access columns in a row but always displays empty string when using `Row.Cells[1].Text` I am using this code in GridView Unload event handler.

Thanks inn advance.

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in grvSearchRingTone.Rows)
{
    String coltext = row.Cells[1].Text;
}
```

Comment: Infact what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done in Gridviews `RowDataBound` Event ie

```
 protected void gvUsers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    {
      String coltext =  e.Row.Cells[1].Text
    }
 else if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
          String coltext =  e.Row.Cells[1].Text
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using the `Gridview Databound event` instead. Because the

> Unload event occurs when the server control is unloaded from memory.

```
protected void  GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach (GridViewRow row in grvSearchRingTone.Rows)
  {
    String coltext = row.Cells[1].Text;
  }
}
```

> Databound events occur after the server control binds to a data source.

To understand how gridview events work, look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview_events.aspx)